# How can I set tabs if the New product is in a certain type

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

In the Woocommerce Admin Tab for Products,
I want the product tabs to reflect a custom layout when a user adds a new product.

Now I have working code for when a product exits but I want this to reflect also when a user clicks to add a new product (you know the screen before the product is inserted into the database? )

So this is the working code I'm testing with

```
function Reboot_remove_linked_products($tabs){
    global $post;
    $Product_is_what_Im_looking_for=false;
    if ( is_product() && has_term( 'Forensic Evidence', 'product_cat' ) ) {
        $Product_is_what_Im_looking_for= true;
    }elseif( is_product() && has_category( 'Forensic Evidence' ) ) {
        $Product_is_what_Im_looking_for= true;
    }

    if ($Product_is_what_Im_looking_for== true){
        unset($tabs['general']);
            unset($tabs['inventory']);
            unset($tabs['shipping']);
            unset($tabs['linked_product']);
            unset($tabs['attribute']);
            unset($tabs['advanced']);

    }
    return($tabs);
}

add_filter('woocommerce_product_data_tabs', 'Reboot_remove_linked_products', 10, 1);
```

Comment: You can use this hook woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button ,
It's work before add to cart.
and you can also use this hook "woocommerce_add_to_cart" , It's work with add to cart

Comment: Sorry, there is a miss understanding .. will try rephrase the question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So took too long to figure this out but the answer is surprisingly simple and was actually in the Woocommerce documentation ..

```
function Reboot_remove_linked_products($tabs){
    $tabs['inventory']['class'][] = 'hide_if_forensic_evidence';
    $tabs['shipping']['class'][] = 'hide_if_forensic_evidence';
    $tabs['linked_product']['class'][] = 'hide_if_forensic_evidence';
    $tabs['attribute']['class'][] = 'hide_if_forensic_evidence';
    $tabs['advanced']['class'][] = 'hide_if_forensic_evidence';
    return($tabs);
}
add_filter('woocommerce_product_data_tabs', 'Reboot_remove_linked_products', 10, 1);
```

So what is going on you ask?
So the tabs in standard form are never unset when switching product types according to Woo.
They have built in functions to hide the tab based on the product type selected.

so **ALL** you have to do is add a class called "hide_if" with your custom product type.
So in my case it's "hide_if_forensic_evidence".
You do this to all the tabs you want "disabled"

Woo will automatically know to hide those tabs when your product type is selected.

Answer (score 0):

May be you should change priority of that hook like this:-

```
add_filter('woocommerce_product_data_tabs', 'Reboot_remove_linked_products', 999, 1);
```

For the new screen, you have to check whether product is published or not.

**UPDATED Code:-**

```
function Reboot_remove_linked_products($tabs){
    global $post;
    $Product_is_what_Im_looking_for=false;
    if ( is_product() && has_term( 'Forensic Evidence', 'product_cat' ) ) {
        $Product_is_what_Im_looking_for= true;
    }elseif( is_product() && has_category( 'Forensic Evidence' ) ) {
        $Product_is_what_Im_looking_for= true;
    } elseif('publish' === get_post_status( $post->ID )) {
        $Product_is_what_Im_looking_for= true;
    }

    if ($Product_is_what_Im_looking_for== true){
        unset($tabs['general']);
            unset($tabs['inventory']);
            unset($tabs['shipping']);
            unset($tabs['linked_product']);
            unset($tabs['attribute']);
            unset($tabs['advanced']);

    }
    return($tabs);
}

add_filter('woocommerce_product_data_tabs', 'Reboot_remove_linked_products', 999, 1);
```

Comment: No, returns same result, fine when the product exists but on the new screen it still reflects the default layout.

Comment: The priority is the third argument but not the last one, which is the number of arguments in the function…

Comment: Should I add perhaps a screen shot to show the new product screen ? Maybe this is where people might be misunderstanding the question ..